# Plot a function including an integral

Tags: r, plot

I would like to curve a function v defined as follows:

```
u<-function(x){log(x^2+1)}

v<-function(x){integrate(v,0,x)}
```

When I use the command `curve(v,1,2,10)`, the result is

```
Error in curve(v, 1, 2, 10) : 
  'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'
```

Please help me to plot the curve of the function v.

Comment: `v <- Vectorize(function(x) {integrate(u, 0, x)$value})`

Answer (score 5):

You have a typo, it should be `integrate(u, ...)`, not `v`.
And you must have function `v` return a vector. Like this:

```
u <- function(x){log(x^2+1)}

v <- function(x){
    sapply(x, function(.x) integrate(u, 0, .x)$value)
}

curve(v, from = 1, to = 2, n = 10)
```

[image]